# Create a user desired input number of objects C++

Tags: c++, oop, input

I have a pretty simple question. I have a program that prompts the user for how many people are desired for a simulation within the program. I am wondering how I would go about initializing the value of the cin objects. Here is a snippet of what I'm looking at:

```
cout<<"Number of users? ";
int users;
cin>>users;
```

The basics^. I want to take the input I get for users and make this many people objects. I have a class called CPerson that has several basic member functions like getName() and getGender(). I'm not so concerned with these. I then need to be able to put the number of users created into a queue which I figure won't be so hard once I have the objects initialized.

Thank you for any help.

UPDATE:
I ended up with something that looked like this which yielded desired results. Thanks to all.

```
vector<CPerson*> people;
for (unsigned int x=0; x<users; x++) {
    CPerson *user = new CPerson(Names[x]);
    people.push_back(user);
    cout<<user->getName()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Look into the standard libraries options for storage containers, you may benefit most from `std::vector`.

Comment: @izuriel I am trying to implement a vector but the compiler throws an exception about the vector subscript being out of range. `vector<CPerson*> user;                                              for (unsigned int x=0; x<numUsers; x++) {
        CPerson *people;
        people = user[x];
 }`

Comment: @zweed4u That's definitely wrong. What is that code doing?

Comment: Just for you to know, this code leaks memory...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos thanks for the heads up. No worries though. I checked for memory leaks and had the logic in my main file. =)

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the input from the user you can then create a dynamic array:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;

int* array = new int[n];
// ...
delete[] array;
```

Or you can use `std::vector` where the size can accommodate the users input.

Comment: I thought array sizes in C++ had to be compile time constants? Or is this a relatively new feature of C++?

Comment: @izuriel This is true only when you are creating an array on the stack (the size must be known at compile time). Since we are allocating on the heap, *and* the size is known at runtime, this works fine.